# Disabling overscroll on an AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-widget

When implementing my own ListView, I can call setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER) to turn off the overscroll bars.

AutoCompleteTextView automatically creates its own ListView (presumably) for its dropdown list. Is there a way to turn off overscroll for this ListView?

Comment: I doubt you can do that(easily). The `ListView` with the results is placed in a `PopupWindow` which is not available outside of the `AutoCompleteTextView`. More, you'll have additional work to do as every time the popup is shown it sets its `ListView` to `View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS`.